Torque required to turn an auger
I have a horizontal auger that has a defined pitch, length, and radius. I want to fill said auger with a sand-like material with a defined density to a certain percentage, and then have the auger spin. How would I go about finding the torque required to do so? I'm looking to find a general equation (however rough it may be) for this instead of finding an exact number because literally all the "defined" dimensions are likely going to be changed.
Thanks in advance!

All I can say is don't calculate it like the idiots at Camp Chef who built a pellet grill with a shear pin on the augur that is a nightmare to replace.

With 2 provisoes use this equation (from Shigley and Mischke):
T=F (d_m/2) [sin(a) + u cos (a)] / [cos (a) - u sin (a)]
F= force/load being moved
d_m = mean diameter
u = coef of friction
a = lead angle of auger
Stolen from https://www.eng-tips.com/threads/calculating-torque-with-auger.81705/
Proviso 1 - I can't find it in my copy of Shigley and Mischke
Proviso 2 - I don't think it accounts for friction between the material and the tube.
However much more useful is
https://www.kwsmfg.com/engineering-guides/screw-conveyor/bulk-material-table/
and
https://www.kwsmfg.com/engineering-guides/screw-conveyor/screw-conveyor-horsepower/
and here's a calculator
https://www.kwsmfg.com/engineering-guides/screw-conveyor/kws-calculators/
